# Enable Echo Request Win Server 2008

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, firewall, performance, ping

Using Windows Server 2008 R2.

The server is working as expected and all network connectivity is fine. However I noticed that I was unable to ping the server IP **from** another client PC on the same LAN.

I read [this article](https://www.petri.com/enable-ping-windows-2008-server) explaining how to enable `File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)` in the server firewall.

Having enabled this rule in the firewall and I am now able to ping the server successfully.

I have two questions;

- why isn't this rule enables by default?
- will enabling the rule have any adverse impact on the server (security or performance)?

Thanks

Comment: `The server is working as expected and all network connectivity is fine. However I noticed that I was unable to ping the server IP from another client PC on the same LAN.` - Why is this important to you? Why do you want to be able to ping the server? What value or use will this have for you?